# How can I send two values with Axios in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to send a comment to my API. This comment is related to an article. So the three values I need to send are the user name, the content of the comment and the post the comment is related to.

A the moment I just succeeded sending the user name and the content to my API, but it didn't send the post the comment was related to.

Here is what I tried :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import CommentsAPI from '../../Services/CommentsAPI'

export default function CommentForm() {

    const [comment, setComment] = useState({})
    const {id_post} = useParams()

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            CommentsAPI.create(JSON.parse(`{"data":{"id":${id_post}, "attributes":${JSON.stringify(comment)}}}`))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.currentTarget
        setComment({
            ...comment,
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <TextField 
                    id="pseudo" 
                    label="Pseudo" 
                    type="text" 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="pseudo"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <TextField
                    id="comment"
                    label="Comment"
                    multiline
                    minRows={2}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="content"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                    Send
                </Button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

```
import { URL_COMMENTS } from '../config'
import axios from 'axios'

function create(id_post, comment) {
    return axios.post(URL_COMMENTS, id_post, comment)
}

const CommentsAPI = {
    create
}

export default CommentsAPI
```

Comment: Do you actually build a string that is supposed to be JSON only to turn around and parse it? You should just use a JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want something like this:

```
import { URL_COMMENTS } from '../config'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function create(id_post, comment) {

      const data = {
      //pass your data here
      userName : yourUserName,
      comment : yourComment,
      postRelated : post
   }
  //sending data through api call
  axios.post(URL_COMMENTS, data).then((response)=>{
    //here your function returns the data gotten from your api
    return response.data;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your **create(id_post, comment)** function requires 2 arguments, while you're passing only one:

```
CommentsAPI.create(JSON.parse(`{"data":{"id":${id_post}, "attributes":${JSON.stringify(comment)}}}`))
```

Just try to pass two arguments, like so:

```
CommentsAPI.create(id_post, JSON.stringify(comment));
```

Also according to axios docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro
axios.post uses three arguments:
axios.post(url, data, config), so currently you are passing comment as config to axios. Config is not required argument.

Try this (data object should look like request body provided by your backend):

```
function create(id_post, comment) {
    const data = {
      id: id_post,
      comment: comment,
    };
    return axios.post(URL_COMMENTS, data);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the server responded 400 (Bad request).

Comment: I could have something in my API by having this in my code : JSON.parse(`{"data":${JSON.stringify(comment)}}`). The only problem is that I didn't find the right way to get also the post related to my comment...

Comment: Also check in your API docs, how should request body look like, make sure you're sending it the right way. In example:
`{
  id: id_post,
  comment: comment,
}`
Might be incorrect, because your api may require some different object keys.

Comment: @EmilieTossan maybe your backend API requires you to send comment only?
Like:
`return axios.post(URL_COMMENTS, {data: JSON.stringify(comment)});`

Comment: Yes it worked, but I am missing the post ID.

Comment: Oh, I just found my mistake.

Comment: And does your code work for now? :)

Comment: Yes it worked ! I confused the post id with the comment id. 